# Reversing the checksum based on the data

Tags: protocols, reverse-engineering, decode, checksum, crc

I'm trying to reverse the binary protocol of embedded device. I was able to capture 4 samples of data packages, here they are in hex encoded form:

```
5E:A1:00:10:10:00:00:02:01:05:F0:F6:4B:00:01:03
5E:A1:00:10:10:00:00:06:01:93:79:DA:F9:00:01:07
5E:A1:00:10:10:00:00:03:01:C9:B1:F0:81:00:01:04
5E:A1:00:10:10:00:00:04:01:A3:BE:2A:3A:00:01:05
```

Based on other packages I can assert the following:

1. First 6 bytes (5E:A1:00:10:10:00) - message header, it's static across all other messages.
2. Next 2 bytes (00:02 or 00:06 or 00:03 or 00:04) - the message numeric id, int16. It's different from message to message.
3. Next 4 bytes (05:F0:F6:4B or 93:79:DA:F9 or C9:B1:F0:81 or A3:BE:2A:3A) is a checksum of a message. It depends on the data and the message number. I tried that by forming the package manually: when I update bytes in data area of a message or the message number, but not the checksum - the message gets declined by the remote server.
4. Everything else is just a data of variable length.

My question is: how can I understand the algorithm used for the checksum generation? Is there any software which can be used for that kind of purpose? For example, I input the mask in the data and it tries to guess the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a CRC, then [reveng](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/) may be able to deduce the parameters of the CRC, given enough examples.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you very much for your advice. Unfortunately, I checked it in reveng with 30+ samples and that gave me no result. I even tried to put checksum at the end of the hex encoded string, but still no model been detected. So I assume it's not a default CRC, but some unknown custom implementation.

Comment: Did you try the `-s` option?  You may also need to try different combinations of what does and does not constitute the message that the CRC is computed on.